# ubuntu grep command

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, grep, regex

i wanna find all cicle for into ubuntu

i write: grep for(* /usr/include

don't work...why?

Comment: Could you add more information? I really don't understand your question. What is "cicle for into ubuntu"?

Comment: Folks, I agree that the question is hard to understand, but I'm not sure that dumping -1's on someone who may not be a native English speaker is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`for(*` is not a valid regular expression.  If you are trying to match the literal text `for(`, try `fgrep` instead of `grep`.  If you're trying to do something else, please clarify what you are trying to search for.

Note that `*` in regular expressions does not work like `*` in wildcards (in regex, it means "zero or more of the previous character", not "any sequence of characters").

Also: `/usr/include` is a directory name, not a filename or wildcard pattern matching filenames.  You may want `/usr/include/*.h` or an idiom involving `find ... -print | xargs grep ...`, but again it would help to have a clearer idea of what you're trying to do.